# Ruby/Watir disable Save password prompt

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, watir

This question relates to automation testing in chrome using Rubymine, Watir and Selenium.
How do we disable this from popping up in Chrome

[image]

These are our current options for chromedriver

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
      options: {"excludeSwitches" => ["enable-automation", "load-extension"]},
      args: ["ignore-certificate-errors", "disable-infobars"]
  )
  options.add_preference(:credentials_enable_service, false)
  options.add_preference(:password_manager_enabled, false)
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

Comment: I will tell you another idea if you are using the same username and password. Are you?

Comment: It comes from a pool of 10 possible names/pwords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using Preferences**

You are setting the preferences correctly. The problem is that you're running into a bug in Selenium-WebDriver - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7917.

Until the fix is released, you'll need to use Strings for the preferences instead of Symbols:

```
options.add_preference("credentials_enable_service", false)
options.add_preference("password_manager_enabled", false)
```

Note that you don not need to create the Selenium Options directly. You can let Watir do this for you:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(
  :chrome,
  options: {
    options: {"excludeSwitches" => ["enable-automation", "load-extension"]},
    args: ["ignore-certificate-errors", "disable-infobars", '--disable-features=RendererCodeIntegrity'],
    prefs: {"credentials_enable_service" => false, "password_manager_enabled" => false}
  }
)
```

**Using Incognito**

Alternatively, instead of setting preferences, you could use incognito mode:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
  options: {"excludeSwitches" => ["enable-automation", "load-extension"]},
  args: ["incognito", "ignore-certificate-errors", "disable-infobars"]
)
```

Comment: This is actually the answer!

Comment: hi, I have already has the options key in my browser declaration like b=Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: prefs}. If so, how can I include your option along with my settings?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, the preferences would be added to your `prefs` Hash. See the updated answer, which shows how this entire configuration could be done without manually creating the Selenium Options object.

Comment: Hi Justin, Your given answer works perfectly, thanks. End of each test cases I am closing off the browser, and when I open the browser again, it gives the pop up at the right top corner with the message `Restore pages? Chrome didn't shut down correctly`. I don't know why I get this, but is there any way to avoid this pop up?

Comment: Sorry @Rajagopalan, cannot say I've run into that myself. As far as I can tell, it's a Chromedriver issue with using existing profiles. The best option is likely to stop using an existing profile - ie see if you can automate all the configuration instead. It also sounds like [Issue 3370](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3370#c11) could be related to your problem and is scheduled to be released in Chromedriver 86.

Comment: That's exactly my problem, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I will tell you a way. So now our goal is to press the `Never` button and browser has to remember that choice thereby it would not ask you again. So What we have to do here is, We have to click that `Never` and save in the profile which program loads. So do as I say. Allow this pop up to show up and know which line it is in the program and after that line, just write sleep 20 seconds temporarily later you can remove this statement. Once the program reaches here,it would wait for you 20 seconds so manually press that never button now this choice will be stored in the profile program loads so next time when program loads it wouldn't ask you. And when you run next time, remove this sleep 20.

Comment: Won't the prompt come back each time you create a new Chrome instance? I think this would only work if you're re-using the same profile.

Comment: You are perfectly correct. He has to load the same profile.